# Copy C++ FFmpeg AVFrame to C# WritableBitmap

Tags: c#, c++, ffmpeg

I have a C++ function definition with ffmpeg scaler The last two parameter is my question (buffer and stride):

```
int scale_decoded_video_frame(void* handle, void* scalerHandle, void* scaledBuffer, int scaledBufferStride) 

sws_scale(
    scalerContext->sws_context,
    srcData,
    context->frame->linesize,
    0, 
    scalerContext->source_height,
    reinterpret_cast<uint8_t**>(&scaledBuffer),
    &scaledBufferStride);
```

When I declared it in C# I use the following code:

```
[DllImport(LibraryName, EntryPoint = "scale_decoded_video_frame", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int ScaleDecodedVideoFrame(IntPtr handle, IntPtr scalerHandle, IntPtr scaledBuffer, int scaledBufferStride);
```

And the C# call:

```
WriteableBitmap w = new WriteableBitmap(1920, 1080, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null);
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(w, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);
w.Lock();

Int32Rect rect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, 1920, 1080);

resultCode = FFmpegVideoPInvoke.ScaleDecodedVideoFrame(decoderPtr, scalerHandle, w.BackBuffer, w.BackBufferStride);
if (resultCode == 0)
   w.AddDirtyRect(rect);

w.Unlock();
```

**It works perfect, but I want to skip the scale function and only want to get the decoded image to the WritableBitmap buffer**. I try to use this code, change the sws_scale function to memcpy, but it shows nothing. The context->frame is AVFrame*.

```
memcpy(scaledBuffer, context->frame->data, AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS * sizeof(uint8_t));
memcpy(&scaledBufferStride, context->frame->linesize, AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS * sizeof(int));
```

How can I copy the AVFrame buffer to the WritableBitmap buffer?

Comment: We can't see from your post, what is the format of the decoded image. Assuming format is YUV420P (and assume the data of each plane is continuous in memory), you may need three `memcpy` - one for `Y` plane, one for `U` plane and one for `V` plane. In the general case you need something like [memcpy2D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74882234/4926757). You may store each plane in separate `WriteableBitmap` (one for `Y`, one for `U` and one for `V`, when Y is 1920x1080 and U and V are 960x540 each), or store 1920x1620 in one `WriteableBitmap`. In both cases use `PixelFormats.Gray8`.

Comment: The decoded frame->format can be YUV420P, YUVJ420P (depending of my camera) if I use decoding without hw acceleration, but if I use hw accel it can be NV12 because of av_hwframe_transfer_data function. I see that all of them is planar YUV 4:2:0, 12bpp but is it possible to copy data with a simple ffmpeg build in function? My problem is that if my user buy a camera with another pixel format, I don't want to release another sw.

Comment: And you see, that the WritableBitmap format is Pbgra32, so my decoded frame output format must be AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA. Am I right? So I see a "fast" function that convert the pixel format, but not scale the image. Is there any way to do that during the decoding with GPU?

Comment: About the fist question, I am not aware of simple FFmpeg build in function to copy data. It may be possible to copy data using `sws_scale` (I don't know). About scaling using the GPU, I know it's possible, but I don't know how to do it with the C interface of FFmpeg.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will check sws_scale with hw acceleration.

Comment: The HW acceleration uses a filter - not sws_scale